# Compiling Latex in Vim Results in Error

Tags: vim, pdftex, latexmk

I am trying to compile the following LaTeX using `vimtex` continuous compiling in `vim`:

**LaTeX:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{Electrolysis of Water and Aqueous Solutions}
\author{Carlo Abelli \\ AP Chemistry --- Mr.\ Kern}
\date{February 19, 2015}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \end{titlepage}
  \section{Water Electrolysis Calculations and Questions}
  \subsection{Half Reaction for Each Electrode}
  Cathode (reduction): \(2H^{+}_{(aq)} + 2e^{-} \rightarrow H_{2(g)}\)\\
  This reaction took place at the cathode because during the splint test the gas
  produced a popping sound, characteristic of hydrogen, a highly flammable gas.
  \\
  \\
  Anode (oxidation): \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} \rightarrow O_{2(g)} + 4H^{+}_{(aq)} +
   4e^{-}\)\\
  This reaction took place at the anode because during the splint test the gas
  reignited the splint ember, characteristic of oxygen.
  \subsection{Overall Reaction}
  \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} \rightarrow 2H_{2(g)} + O_{2(g)}\)
  \subsection{Average Current}
  Average Current: \(\frac{0.44 + 0.43 + 0.44 + 0.44 + 0.45 + 0.46 + 0.45 + 0.46
    + 0.46 + 0.45 + 0.45 + 0.46 + 0.45 + 0.47 + 0.46}{15} = 0.45\)
  \subsection{Amount of Hydrogen Produced in One Hour}
  \(\frac{0.45\ coulombs}{1.00\ \sec} * \frac{60.0\ \sec}{1.00\ \min} *
    \frac{60.0\ \min}{1.00\ hour} * \frac{1.00\ e^{-}}{1.60*10^{-19}\ coulombs} *
    \frac{1.00\ mol\ e^{-}}{6.022*10^{23}\ e^{-}} * \frac{1.00\ mol\ H_{2}}
    {2.00\ mol\ e^{-}} = 0.0084\ mol\ H_{2}\)\\
  \(0.0084\ mol\ H_{2} * 22.4\ L/mol = 0.19\ L\ H_{2}\)\\
  \(0.0084\ mol\ H_{2} * 2.016\ g/mol = 0.0017\ g\ H_{2}\)
  \subsection{Amount of Time Needed to Produce 30 mL Oxygen Gas at
  22\(^{\circ}\)C and 1.00 atm}
  \(1.00\ atm * 0.030\ L = n * 0.08206\ L\ atm\ K^{-1}\ mol^{-1} * 295\ K\)\\
  \(n = 0.0012\ mol\ O_{2}\)\\
  \(0.0012\ mol\ O_{2} * \frac{4.00\ mol\ e^{-}}{1.00\ mol\ O_{2}} *
    \frac{6.022*10^{23}\ e^{-}}{1.00\ mol\ e^{-}} *
    \frac{1.60*10^{-19}\ coulombs}{1\ e^{-}} * \frac{1.00\ \sec}{0.45\ coulombs}
    = 100.\ \sec\)
  \subsection{Moles of Gas Produced in Experiment}
  Cathode (Hydrogen)\\
  \(P_{container} = 36.8\ cm\ H_{2}O * \frac{10.0\ mm}{1.00\ cm} *
    \frac{1.08\ g\ H_{2}O} {1\ mL\ H_{2}O} * \frac{1\ mL\ Hg}
    {13.534\ g\ Hg} + 751.1\ mm\ Hg = 780.5\ mm\ Hg\)\\
  \(P_{gas} = P_{container} - P_{H_{2}O}\)\\
  \(P_{gas} = 780.5\ mm\ Hg - 18.7\ mm\ Hg = 761.8\ mm\ Hg\)\\
  \(761.8\ mm\ Hg * 0.0486\ L = n * 62.363\ L\ mmHg\ K^{-1}\ mol^{-1} * 294.0\ K\)
  \\
  \(n = 0.00202\ mol\ H_{2}\)\\
  \\
  Anode (Oxygen)\\
  \(P_{container} = 24.0\ cm\ H_{2}O * \frac{10.0\ mm}{1.00\ cm} *
    \frac{1.08\ g\ H_{2}O} {1\ mL\ H_{2}O} * \frac{1\ mL\ Hg}
    {13.534\ g\ Hg} + 751.1\ mm\ Hg = 770.3\ mm\ Hg\)\\
  \(P_{gas} = P_{container} - P_{H_{2}O}\)\\
  \(P_{gas} = 770.3\ mm\ Hg - 18.7\ mm\ Hg = 751.6\ mm\ Hg\)\\
  \(751.6\ mm\ Hg * 0.0239\ L = n * 62.363\ L\ mmHg\ K^{-1}\ mol^{-1} * 294.0\ K\)
  \\
  \(n = 0.000980\ mol\ O_{2}\)
  \subsection{Theoretical Moles of Gas Produced}
  Cathode (Hydrogen)\\
  \(\frac{0.45\ coulombs}{1.00\ \sec} * \frac{60.0\ \sec}{1.00\ \min} * 14.0\ \min *
    \frac{1.00\ e^{-}}{1.60*10^{-19}\ coulombs} * \frac{1.00\ mol\ e^{-}}
    {6.022*10^{23}\ e^{-}} * \frac{1.00\ mol\ H_{2}}{2.00\ mol\ e^{-}} =
    0.0020\ mol\ H_{2}\)\\
  \\
  Anode (Oxygen)\\
  \(\frac{0.45\ coulombs}{1.00\ \sec} * \frac{60.0\ \sec}{1.00\ \min} * 14.0\ \min *
    \frac{1.00\ e^{-}}{1.60*10^{-19}\ coulombs} * \frac{1.00\ mol\ e^{-}}
    {6.022*10^{23}\ e^{-}} * \frac{1.00\ mol\ O_{2}}{4.00\ mol\ e^{-}} =
    0.00098\ mol\ O_{2}\)
  \subsection{Percent Deviation}
  Cathode (Hydrogen)\\
  \(\frac{0.00202\ mol - 0.0020\ mol}{0.0020\ mol} * 100 = 0.0\%\ deviation\)\\
  \\
  Anode (Oxygen)\\
  \(\frac{0.000980\ mol - 0.00098\ mol}{0.00098\ mol} * 100 = 0.0\%\ deviation\)
  \section{Aqueous KI, KBr and KCl Electrolysis Calculations and Questions}
  \subsection{Half Reactions for Each Electrode}
  \begin{tabular}{ l r @{\(\rightarrow\)} l }
    KI Solution\\
    Cathode (reduction): & \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} + 2e^{-}\) &
      \(2OH^{-}_{(aq)} + H_{2(g)}\)\\
    Anode (oxidation): & \(2I^{-}_{(aq)}\) & \(I_{2(s)} + 2e^{-}\)\\
    \\
    KBr Solution\\
    Cathode (reduction): & \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} + 2e^{-}\) &
      \(2OH^{-}_{(aq)} + H_{2(g)}\)\\
    Anode (oxidation): & \(2Br^{-}_{(aq)}\) & \(Br_{2(l)} + 2e^{-}\)\\
    \\
    KCl Solution\\
    Cathode (reduction): & \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} + 2e^{-}\) &
      \(2OH^{-}_{(aq)} + H_{2(g)}\)\\
    Anode (oxidation): & \(2Cl^{-}_{(aq)}\) & \(Cl_{2(g)} + 2e^{-}\)\\
  \end{tabular}\\
  \\
  The water half reaction had to have occurred at the cathode because the
  phenolphthalein indicator was activated by the creation of \(OH^{-}\),
  creating the purple color observed at the cathode.\\
  \\
  The iodine, chlorine and bromine half reactions had to have occurred at the
  anode because in the first experiment, a dark solid was created at the anode
  (iodine), in the second experiment, a yellow liquid was observed (bromine)
  and in the third experiment, a chlorine smelling gas was produced (chlorine).
  \subsection{Overall Equations}
  \begin{tabular}{ l r @{\(\rightarrow\)} l }
    KI Solution: & \(KI_{(aq)} + 2H_{2}O_{(l)}\) & \(KOH_{(aq)} + 2H_{2(g)} +
      I_{2(s)}\)\\
    KBr Solution: & \(KBr_{(aq)} + 2H_{2}O_{(l)}\) & \(KOH_{(aq)} + 2H_{2(g)} +
      Br_{2(l)}\)\\
    KCl Solution: & \(KCl_{(aq)} + 2H_{2}O_{(l)}\) & \(KOH_{(aq)} + 2H_{2(g)} +
      Cl_{2(g)}\)\\
    Test Solution:
  \end{tabular}
  \subsection{Half Reactions and Overall Equation for Molten KI, KBr and KCl}
  KI\\
  \begin{tabular}{ l r @{\(\rightarrow\)} l }
    Cathode (reduction): & \(K^{+}_{(l)} + e^{-}\) & \(K_{(s)}\)\\
    Anode (oxidation): & \(2I^{-}_{(l)}\) & \(I_{2(s)} + 2e^{-}\)\\
    Overall Equation: & \(2KI_{(l)}\) & \(2K_{(s)} + I_{2(s)}\)\\
  \end{tabular}\\
  \\
  KBr\\
  \begin{tabular}{ l r @{\(\rightarrow\)} l }
    Cathode (reduction): & \(K^{+}_{(l)} + e^{-}\) & \(K_{(s)}\)\\
    Anode (oxidation): & \(2Br^{-}_{(l)}\) & \(Br_{2(l)} + 2e^{-}\)\\
    Overall Equation: & \(2KBr_{(l)}\) & \(2K_{(s)} + Br_{2(s)}\)\\
  \end{tabular}\\
  \\
  KCl\\
  \begin{tabular}{ l r @{\(\rightarrow\)} l }
    Cathode (reduction): & \(K^{+}_{(l)} + e^{-}\) & \(K_{(s)}\)\\
    Anode (oxidation): & \(2Cl^{-}_{(l)}\) & \(Cl_{2(g)} + 2e^{-}\)\\
    Overall Equation: & \(2KCl_{(l)}\) & \(2K_{(s)} + Cl_{2(g)}\)\\
  \end{tabular}
  \subsection{Time Required to Produce 1.25 g Iodine at 0.75 amps}
  \(1.25\ g\ I_{2} * \frac{1.00\ mol\ I_{2}}{253.80\ g} *
    \frac{2.00\ mol\ e^{-}}{1.00\ mol\ I_{2}} *
    \frac{6.022*10^{23}\ e^{-}}{1.00\ mol\ e^{-}} *
    \frac{1.60*10^{-19}\ coulombs}{1.00\ e^{-}} *
    \frac{1.00\ \sec}{0.75\ coulombs} *
    \frac{1.00\ \min}{60.0\ \sec} = 21\ \min\)
  \subsection{Time Required to Produce 0.100 L Hydrogen gas in Lab Conditions at
    0.75 amps}
  \(751.1\ mmHg * 0.100\ L\ H_{2} = n * 62.363\ L\ mmHg\ K^{-1}\ mol^{-1} *
  294\ K\)\\
  \(n = 0.00410\ mol\)\\
  \(0.00410\ mol\ H_{2} * \frac{2.00\ mol\ e^{-}}{1.00\ mol\ H_{2}} *
    \frac{6.022*10^{23}\ e^{-}}{1.00\ mol\ e^{-}} *
    \frac{1.60*10^{-19}\ coulombs}{1.00\ e^{-}} *
    \frac{1.00\ \sec}{0.75\ coulombs} * \frac{1.00\ \min}{60.0\ \sec} = 18\ \min\)
\end{document}
```

**Log file:**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2015.7.9)  30 JUL 2015 20:50
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.tex
(./electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
) (./electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.aux)
\openout1 = `electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <14.4> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 10.
[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 15.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 15--24

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 45--64

 []

[1]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 65--76

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 77--82

 []


./electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.tex:86: LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.86 ...reduction): & \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} + 2e^{-}\) &

? 
./electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.tex:86: Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.86 ...reduction): & \(2H_{2}O_{(l)} + 2e^{-}\) &

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 755 strings out of 495028
 10634 string characters out of 6181498
 69479 words of memory out of 5000000
 4022 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 8501 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,8n,32p,516b,207s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
./electrolysis_of_water_and_aqueous_solutions.tex:86:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Why is this happening? I can't figure it out. Running `pdflatex` from the command line does indeed generate the pdf (after generating a few warnings) so the problem must come from `latexmk`, `vimtex` or `vim`, right?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `$`...`$` instead of `\(`...`\)`.

Comment: @Werner may be just in tabular preambul `$\rightarrow$`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it using `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` to make `\(` and `\)` robust. Now compiles without errors.

Comment: You need to update your distribution, since `fixltx2e` now forms part of the default LaTeX loading without having to do it manually.

Comment: @Werner Using `texlive` in Mint which is the most recent version I can get. Strange they haven't updated yet but maybe soon.

Comment: @Werner The version I am using as reported by `tex --version` is `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`. Do you know in which version they made this the default?

Comment: Yes, TeX Live 2015... You're (Debian is) a tad behind...

Comment: @Werner Yeah figured 2013 was a bit outdated...Is there any way to get the newest via a `ppa` or something without compiling manually?

Comment: See [How to update my TeX distribution](http://goo.gl/CqWB1).

Comment: @Werner Thanks for that, but I think this will be the final push I need to switch over to `arch`